# JMeter takes long time to download resource

Tags: download, jmeter, mp4

I am testing a static pages of website. I am talking only about homepage here. This home page takes around 20 seconds for full download and in around 6 sec you would see the page ( so user perspective is good)

now that page has eleven mp4 files, and in JMeter they take long time to download, why is that? In Google developer tool that page shows download completed in around 20 sec but my JMeter recorded script reports 60 sec for downloading all resources.

I also used Parallel controller with 6 connection but with that too it reports around 1 min of response time for the whole page. ..and once again, it takes around 20 min in Chrome to download all content.

If I use main(first) URL of homepage and check "Retrieve all embedded resources", then all resources would be downloaded but mp4 files are not downloaded. Why is that?

I also have all recorded requests of the homepage. And if I run those requests then all requests are fine but mp4 takes more time to download than they take in Chrome and response time goes to around 60 sec.

I tried my best to explain the scenario. Please Please help. Your help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that these .mp4 files are being downloaded when the user opens the page?
2. If yes, are you sure that they're being downloaded fully, for example most common scenario is that the server sends [Content-Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range) telling the browser which part of the .mp4 file(s) to fetch
3. If no - you shouldn't be downloading them in your JMeter test at all. Compare the traffic from the real browser and from JMeter using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure that JMeter sends the same request as browser does
4. Try opening the page in browser with clear [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching). It might be the case that the browser has cached the heavy content hence no actual requests are being made and multimedia resources are being returned from memory or disk cache. If this way you will see similar timings - add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your test plan

Comment: 1). Those mp4 files do have content-range header and hence they download with 206 http code. 2) but when i record the script, script does have the request for mp4 files. 3)In chrome with clear cache it takes very less time, only around 20s.  .....why JMeter takes time to download mp4 files but they download fast in chrom?